# Required form field only if previous field is filled

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, validation

**Intro**

I'm developing a wordpress website where I have a form. The validation of that form is made using jQuery Inline Form Validation Engine 2.2.

I have some radio buttons that have two options Yes/No, followed by a required field that only appears if someone chose "No", to explain why. Something like the following example:

> 1 - Is "John Matrix" cooler than "John Rambo"?
>
> → Yes
>
> No
>
> 2 - Is "Commando" the best movie ever?
>
> Yes
>
> → No
>
> Why not? ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_** (* required)

So, if someone would say "No", the "Why not" field appears:

```
if( $('#no_commando_field').is(':checked')) {
    $('#why_not_field').show();
} else {
    $('#why_not_field').hide();
}
```

**Problem**

My problem is that the "Why not" field is required, even if someone selects the "Yes" option (like it's supposed to). I would like to make this field required only if the previous answer is "No".

**Quest to solve problem**

While exploring the code (I'm not a back-end specialist) I realized that the Inline Form Validation Engine adds a class to the required fields, called "validate[required]". I tried deleting that class using jQuery, but the validation still occurs.

```
var validate;
validate = $('#why_not_field').attr('class');
validate = validate.replace('validate[required]','not_validated');
$('#why_not_field').attr('class',validate);

if ( $('#no_commando_field').is(':checked')) {
    validate = validate.replace('not_validated','validate[required]');
    $('#why_not_field').attr('class',validate);
} else {
    validate = validate.replace('validate[required]','not_validated');
    $('#why_not_field').attr('class',validate);
}
```

The class swap is working perfectly, but somehow the validation is still occurring. Although this solution worked for me on previous forms (only on the wordpress backoffice), I'm not sure it is the right path to solve this issue.

I would like someone to point me in the right direction so I can understand this problem better, in order to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use same quotes to open and close selector. `.attr("class')`, should be `.attr("class")`.

Comment: Well spotted. However, that is not my real code, it's just an example.

Comment: I don't know "Inline Form Validation", but from what you are saying I'm assuming it pushes all elements into a array at document.ready. If you are just doing a check to see if there is something inside the required field, writing the validations yourself would safe you alot of time.

Comment: @Naoe Thanks for your reply, it sounds like a good idea. Unfortunately, I don't have the time or knowledge to do something like that at the moment, although I guess it's something I will have to learn in the future.

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer for you, how to create a simple validator. To show how you could do this without spending a lot of time on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy way to check required fields using just jquery.

Just throw this code inside your `$(document).ready(function () { });`

```
$('#SubmitButton').click(function (e) {
    var isValid = true;

    //checks go here

    if (isValid == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Change either the jquery code or the html code to the `SubmitButton` so that the event fires on submit.

For the fields that are required, simply enter the class `required`.

Then do the following checks on the `required` class:

**Check radio buttons**

```
    $('input:radio.required').each(function() {
        nam = $(this).attr('name');
        if ($(':radio[name="'+nam+'"]:checked').length < 1) {             
            $(':radio[name="' + nam + '"]').parent('td').css({
                "border": "1px solid red",
                "background": "#FFCECE"
            });
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            $(':radio[name="' + nam + '"]').parent('td').css({
                "border": "",
                "background": ""
            });
        }
    });
```

**Check textboxes**

```
    $('input:text.required').each(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
            isValid = false;
            $(this).css({
                "border": "1px solid red",
                "background": "#FFCECE"
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).css({
                "border": "",
                "background": ""
            });
        }
    });
```

Here I am changing the background of the fields, but you can do whatever you want.

This way all the checks are worked out at the end, so that you can add and remove the `required` class as the person goes through the form.

**Here is a fiddle demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SCBTj/

**EDIT:**

And to answer your **intitial question**, here is a **demo** on that:

http://jsfiddle.net/SCBTj/2/

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you! My jQuery knowledge improved quite a bit thanks to you. Just one simple thing I don't understand: what is the purpose of `.trim` in this line of code `if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '')`?

Comment: The .trim function removes blank spaces at start and end of a string. In this case we are using it to ensure that a string containing nothing but blank spaces is still considered empty.